# VB.NET TCP/IP Image Sending & Receiving

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, tcp, ip

Hello im having trouble with some VB.NET code below, when i take a screenshot on the client i save it as an image and send it to the server, when the server receives the image it saves it to a folder and my picturebox1 opens that saved image i received and displays it, it works perfect the very first send, but on the second send i get an error given below:

> The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\Root\Desktop\RECEIVED_FILES\01.png' because it is being used
>   by another process.

server/receiving code:

```
Dim Listener As TcpListener = CType(Result.AsyncState, TcpListener)
Dim Client As TcpClient = Listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(Result)
Dim Name As String
Dim Path As String
Dim Data As Long
Dim Binary As New IO.BinaryReader(Client.GetStream)

Name = Binary.ReadString
Data = Binary.ReadInt64
Path = IO.Path.Combine("C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\Desktop\RECEIVED_FILES\", Name)

Dim Buffer(8092) As Byte
Dim ReadTotal As Long = 0
Dim Reading As Integer = -1

'-----------> below is were the error indicated (something with stream) ---------

Using Stream As New IO.FileStream(Path, IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write)
    Do Until ReadTotal = Data
        Reading = Client.GetStream.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)
        Stream.Write(Buffer, 0, Reading)
        ReadTotal += Reading
    Loop
End Using

Binary.Close()
Client.Close()

PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\Desktop\RECEIVED_FILES\01.png")
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Image.FromFile` method locks the file until the `Image` object is disposed.  If you're done with that `Image` object then you should be calling its `Dispose` method anyway, so you can do that first to unlock the file and allow it to be overwritten.

```
If PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing Then
    PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()
End If
```

or, in VB 2017:

```
PictureBox1.Image?.Dispose()
```

You could also set the `ImageLocation` property of the `PictureBox` instead of calling `Image.FromFile` and then you won't lock the file in the first place.  You should still dispose the `Image` when you're done with it though.

```
PictureBox1.ImageLocation = "C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\Desktop\RECEIVED_FILES\01.png")
```

By the way, if you want to get the current user's desktop folder then you should use `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop` or `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)`:

```
PictureBox1.ImageLocation = My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop,
                                                               "RECEIVED_FILES\01.png")
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but, i got this error (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

Comment: Dim Buffer(8092) As Byte
        Dim ReadTotal As Long = 0
        Dim Reading As Integer = -1
        Using Stream As New IO.FileStream(Path, IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write)
            ---------->PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()<----------
            Do Until ReadTotal = Data
                Reading = Client.GetStream.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)
                Stream.Write(Buffer, 0, Reading)
                ReadTotal += Reading
            Loop
        End Using

Comment: You can't dispose an `Image` that doesn't exist.  If you've never assigned an `Image` object to `PictureBox1.Image` then there's nothing to dispose.  I've added some code to my answer that addresses that but it's the sort of thing you need to think about all the time.

Comment: Oh my bad man I see the part of your code after i refreshed the screen, i used your imagelocation tip and it solved the probolem, thank you, best wishes - Alan

Comment: Like I said though, regardless of locking of files, you should still be disposing an `Image` object when you're done with it.  That would mean still adding the first or second code snippet from my answer immediately before setting the `ImageLocation`.

Comment: hey man im back! Ive noticed that after about a few minutes of "live streaming" the pictures from the client my server will no longer receive a new image and the client will go "not repsonding". Sometimes it returns to streaming, sometimes it dosent and im then forced to close the server and client. Could this be a issue with not properly disposing the image properly? or is it a listener or thread issue?

Comment: server code:
            PictureBox1.ImageLocation = ("C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\Desktop\RECEIVED_FILES\01.png")


        Catch ex As Exception
            PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()
            Listener1.Stop()
            Listener1.Start()
        End Try

Comment: You've already accepted an answer because the question you asked has been satisfactorily answered.  If you have a new question then please start a new thread for it with a description that describes the new topic.